# Runtime of for loops where variables depend on outside loops

Tags: java, loops, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a bit of a problem understanding the runtime of nested for loops. I get that:

```
for(int x=0; x<10; x++) // runs 10 times
for(int y=0; y<n; y++) // runs n times

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) // runs n*n = n^2 times
```

However, I get confused when these variables get interlinked. For example:

```
for(int i=0; i < N; i++) // runs n times
    for(int j=i+1; j<N; j++) // runs n*n times but 1 time less every pass?
        for(int k=j+1; k<N; k++) // ???
```

Can you point me in the right direction with a simple explanation on how to approach such a problem?

Comment: It's the *expected*, *best* and *worst* time for a given algorithm. The difference between `N` and `N - 1` (when `N` is **very** large) is insignificant, thus all three loops must be considered O(N), and in combination they would be expected to take `N*N*N` time to run (assuming they don't terminate early).

Comment: Give n a value and substitute to help you figure it out.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But let's just assume I need a formula for the precise amount of passes of a function. How could I work it out for `for(int j=i+1; i<N; j++)`?

Comment: Why do you need such a formula? Big O is about the expected order of a runtime, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The first codeblock was just an example. I will change it to make it clear.

Comment: I need it for an exam which asks for a specific formula for the number of passes. I get that it is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

For just the `i` & `j` loops in the second example, the count will be (N-1)+(N-2)+...+3+2+1, which can be shown to be equal to N(N-1)/2.

Comment: So these equalities would be things I'd have to learn by heart?

Comment: Only if you  need to for a specific class.  In general, understanding Big O is sufficient for making good choices as you develop a program.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Scott's answer...

More generally, the formula is the multiplicative formula for computing binomial coefficients (where n is N from above and k is number of nested loops (3)):

```
(n(n-1)(n-2)…(n-(k-1))) / k!
```

Continued reading:

[Binomial Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

[Falling factorial power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

[And for a specific analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202061/calculating-the-number-of-iterations-in-a-variable-number-of-nested-for-loops)